# Getting error in Merge sort. Can somebody help me out finding error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to do merge sort in SIMPLER WAY but not getting desired output. It is showing me some loop is iterating infinitely. Will anyone help me out finding where is the error in code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void merge(int arr[], int, int, int);
void mergesort(int arr[], int, int);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    mergesort(arr, 0, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int mid, int h) {
    int i = l, j = mid, k = 0;
    int brr[h - l];

    while (i < mid && j < h) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
            brr[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            brr[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for(; i < mid; i++)
        brr[k++] = arr[i];
    for(; j < h; j++)
        brr[k++] = arr[j];
    
    int i = 0;
    for(k = l; k < h; k++)
        arr[k] = brr[i++];
}

void mergesort(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int mid = l + (h - l) / 2;
        mergesort(arr, l, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid, h);
        merge(arr, l, mid, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "it" showing you? Please post the full output

Comment: It is showing mergesort.exe has stopped working,When I am using debugging tool I'm finding that the function mergesort function is iterating infinitely,

Comment: Make it `if(l + 1 < h)` or perhaps more clearly,  `if (h - l > 1)`. You keep sorting one-element subsequences infinitely.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik  making    if(l+1<h)     gives the desired output.

Comment: @desktopp: You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is correct except the test in `mergesort`: `if (l < h)` should be `if (h - l >= 2)`

The test `l < h` is used in when `h` is the index of the last element in the slice. It is much simpler and more idiomatic in C and C++ to consider `h` to be an excluded upper bound. Hence the minimal slice to split in `mergesort` must have a length of at least 2: `h - l >= 2`.

Note that allocating the arrays as VLAs is risky for large arrays: it may cause a **stack overflow**. C++ does not support VLAs (variable length arrays, ie automatic arrays whose size is not a compile time expression), your compiler supports them as an extension.

Note also that the last `for` loop in `merge` can be omitted as the elements it copies are already in the proper position.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void merge(int arr[], int, int, int);
void mergesort(int arr[], int, int);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    mergesort(arr, 0, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int mid, int h) {
    int i = l, j = mid, k = 0;
    int brr[h - l];

    while (i < mid && j < h) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
            brr[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            brr[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for(; i < mid; i++)
        brr[k++] = arr[i];
    
    for(i = 0, k = l; k < j; k++, i++)
        arr[k] = brr[i];
}

void mergesort(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    if (h - l >= 2) {
        int mid = l + (h - l) / 2;
        mergesort(arr, l, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid, h);
        merge(arr, l, mid, h);
    }
}
```